# Postfix redirects info@domain.com to root Maildir?

Tags: email, postfix

Something weird... I'm able to create users without problems, except for 'info'.

All mail sent to 'info@domain.com' gets redirected to /root/Maildir, instead of /home/info/Maildir (which never gets created).

All other accounts are all  right, e.g. when system users are created the Maildir folder is created in their home dir and they correctly get emails.

Any idea? Any help appreciated.

:-/

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/aliases`

There might be an entry in there that  aliases info to root.